# How to do spacing per window on focus with xmonad?

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I`m trying to do spacing around window on focus instead of borders. Its much easier to see, what window is focused.

`XMonad.Actions.Spacing` module does not contain method to make spacing based on window id within this I could do smth like this:

```
myHook ConfigureEvent{ev_event_type = focusIn, ev_window = id} = do
 setSpacing id opacity
```

Is there way to do, what I need?

Comment: Hi. I've seen that you accepted the answer. Just as a curiosity. Did It work as It?, did you modify lot of code?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER**: The code below *HASN'T BEEN TESTED AND LIKELY IT WONT COMPILE*, and even if it compiles, maybe there are good reasons for `xmonad` or `xmonad-contrib` to not export this functionality since it seems to break the tiling setup... This answer doesn't fit in a comment but it should be consider a advise rather than a solution.

You can copy paste some action code and modify to your will. For example mimicking `toggleBorder` from `XMonad.Actions.NoBorders` you can get width and heigth attributes and set them to 95% of its original.

```
-- Maybe more inputs are necesary, check for compiler errors
import XMonad

resizeOnFocus :: Window -> X ()
resizeOnFocus w = do
    withDisplay $ \d -> io $ do
        windowW <- wa_width <$> getWindowAttributes d w
        windowH <- wa_height <$> getWindowAttributes d w
        let newW = floor $ fromIntegral windowW * 0.95
            newH = floor $ fromIntegral windowH * 0.95
        resizeWindow d w newW newH
```

use it with along with `withFocused` as a standard action `((modMask x,  xK_g ),   withFocused resizeOnFocus )`